# Use environment's variables in url parameters with Postman

Tags: environment-variables, postman

Is it possible to use environment variables into url parameters with postman?
See picture below for example :

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I'm using it.

This is my screen.

[image]

My IP is 192.168.0.38 like below.
[image]

Now, I'm working my laptop.

But, If I'm done working, I'll change hostName to the server domain.

Comment: The newer versions of Postman have additional factors to consider which we should be aware of, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754454/is-there-new-syntax-for-using-environment-variables-in-postman-request-urls?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

it's 100% possible, I am using it currently.