# Is there new syntax for using environment variables in Postman request URLs?

Tags: postman

I have used the syntax in the attached screenshot since I started using Postman, but one of the recent updates seems to have either bugged it out or there is new syntax which is not documented on their website. The variable seems to be completely ignored in the request.
[image]

Reference question: [Use environment's variables in url parameters with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39846926/use-environments-variables-in-url-parameters-with-postman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newer versions of the Postman App, the concept of sessions have been introduced using which you can have [session variables](http://blog.getpostman.com/2018/08/09/sessions-faq/) (`current` as shown on variable hover) which allow you to work with variables locally without syncing them with your team.

So in your case, you simply need to reset your current values with your initial values in the `Manage Environments` modal. Screenshot attached for reference.

[Reset variables to replace current values with initial values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TY3I.png)

Additionally, you can configure this behavior in the settings to decide whether or not you would like to persist your current values to the initial values automatically. Screenshot attached for reference.

[Automatically persist variable values toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwTkI.png)

Head over to the [community](https://community.getpostman.com/) forum in case you have additional queries regarding this.

Comment: It would be useful to add this as a potential reason to "Why this might have happened"